# Dynamic Method Naming

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to name methods dynamically (I would not leave it up to user input to do this, but as an example):

```
puts ""
foo = gets
def (whatever the user inputted for foo)
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `send` method to send a message to the class, using the parameter `:define_method` to tell it you are going to define a new method for that class.

For example, having a class `Car`

```
class Car
end

c = Car.new
```

A call to `c.sound` brings about the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sound' for #<Car:0x29d9048>
```

But after defining the name of the method and sending it to the class:

```
input = "sound"

Car.send(:define_method, input) do
  puts "vroom!"
end
```

The call to `c.sound` now brings the output

```
vroom!
```

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used approaches are: `define_method`, `class_eval` and `instance_eval`. Define `method_missing` method is also used a lot.

```
#An example of class_eval
class Foo
end

foo = gets.chomp
#suppose you input bar here
Foo.class_eval %Q{
  def #{foo}
    puts "This is #{foo} method you defined!"
  end
}
Foo.new.bar
#output: This is the bar method you defined!
```

`instance_eval` is used in a similar way but defined on a instance of a class.
`define_method` is also similar:

```
#An example of define_method
klass = Class.new
foo = gets.chomp
#suppose you typed bar
klass.send(:define_method,foo) do
  puts "This is #{foo} method you defined!"
end
klass.new.bar
#output: This is bar method you defined!
```

Search "Ruby Metaprogramming" and there are many tutorials out there.