# DRY code by creating ruby objects/variables dynamically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I am fairly new to Ruby. I have few lines of code I want to DRY them.

```
foo_attributes = params[:foo]
params.delete(:foo)
bar_attributes = params[:bar]
params.delete(:bar)
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
["foo", "bar"].each do |par|
  par_attribute = params[:par]
  params.delete(:par)
end
```

Later in my method, I need to call other methods passing the objects foo_attribute, bar_attribute.

Like:

```
call_foo_method(foo_attribute)
```

How can I do this in ruby?

Comment: You can use [dynamic method dispatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358909/dynamic-method-naming) as well as `eval` and [dynamic attribute setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849521/set-attribute-dynamically-of-ruby-object).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep the `params` var? Then you don't have to assign any other variable at all?

You can also DRY the first (and second example) by combinig two lines:

```
foo_attributes = params.delete(:foo)
bar_attributes = params.delete(:bar)
```